# Lebesgue measure of $\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$

Tags: lebesgue-measure

For $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ I was given this definition of Lebesgue measure:

$m(E)=\sup \{m(K) \mid K\subseteq E \text{ compact}\} = \inf \{m(A) \mid A\supseteq E \text{ open}\}$ if they are equal, where:

$m(K)=\inf\{m(P) \mid P\supseteq K \text{ multi-interval}\}$

$m(A)=\sup\{m(P) \mid P\subseteq A \text{ multi-interval}\}$

(a multi-interval is a finite union of intervals. An interval $I$ is $I=\prod_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j)$. So we might write $P=\bigsqcup_{j=1}^k I_k$, with the natural measure).

Now for $n=1$ and $E:=\mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$ I expect $m(E)$ to be zero. But when I imagine an open set $A\supseteq E$, it never gets a less-than-one measure.
Can somebody give me a hint please?

PS: I don't want to use other ways to find the measure of $E$: I'm looking for a better understanding of the definitions.

Comment: Enmerate the rationals as $q_n$ and place around the $n$-th a ball of radius $r_n/2$ chosen small enough so that $\sum r_n$ converges to a number smaller than $1$

Comment: But the balls will necessarily intersect and therefore (1) the measure won't be $\sum r_n$, and (2) I will still cover all the $[0,1]$ interval. Isn't it so?

Comment: They will overlap, but that means that the actual measure is even less than $\sum r_n$ so there is no issue. And no, not the whole interval will be covered

Comment: The balls don't necessarily cover $[0,1]$. Take for example $c = 1/\pi \in [0,1]$. As $c$ is irrational, for any rational number $q \in [0,1]$ you can take the ball $B(q,(q-c)/4)$. Then $c$ lies in none of those balls, so those balls do not cover $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, that is true, thank you. May I ask you guys if you get to visually see what's happening with the measure provided by the open sets given by the union of those balls? Cause I can't.

Comment: @roddik: What do you mean by "visually see"?

Comment: @tomasz can you draw a mental picture that clarifies by itself the inf of measures attaining to zero?

Comment: Well, you draw these countably many balls of measures adding up to less than infinity, and then you make them progressively smaller. At the limit, you have just ${\mathbf Q}$, which is of course of measure zero (although that is no longer open).

Comment: @tomasz I am sorry, I don't see it :( and you can't say $\mathbf{Q}$ has obviously zero measure if that's what I'm trying to see. I should see the limit of measure attaining to zero.

Comment: @roddik: Well, the measure is countably additive, and points have measure zero, the rationals are countable...

Comment: @tomasz Yes, that is why I added the "PS" at the end of the question: I already know the measure is zero. I need to understand the definition...

Comment: @roddik: The countable additivity is the essence of the definition!

Comment: @tomasz I agree: but this definition does not refer to countable additivity, so it must work without asking its help. This apparently means that the complexity of $\mathbb{Q}$ does indeed not allow the visual representation I was looking for.

Comment: The visual representation is the same for every countable set. So take $\mathbb{N}$ for simplicity. You can wrap your mind about that, then you can see more clearly what is going on with your set.

Comment: @MushuNrek You must be right: I guess we can't do better than that.

Comment: Since the measure in question is zero, you need only focus on showing that there are a countable collection of $n$-intervals that contain the rationals and whose volumes sum to less than $\epsilon$.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti your answer was right. I can choose it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I honestly think I figured out the answer I'd want to receive.

The confusing point is: every open set $A\supseteq E$ is "basically E". The insight that I find satisfying is the following. This is basically the answer provided by @Alessandro Codenotti in the comments section.

The measure of an open set is defined as a $sup$ of measures of $\textit{finite}$ unions of intervals. Since $\textit{any}$ union of open sets is open, I might cover $E$ with a "big" union of $\textit{small}$ open intervals in such a way that any time I try to fill this covering with a countable (actually finite but then I'm taking the limit as a $sup$) number of intervals I am forced to take them so tiny that I can't cover most of $[0,1]$).

So the heart of this definition is the double approximation. In other words *"one gets zero not when he approximates with open sets from outside but when he approximates those open sets from inside with multi-intervals".*

Of course, once you realize it is actually a countably additive measure, everything becomes easier (you basically only need to know $m(x)=0$ $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$).

An **explicit example** is the following.

Take $0<\epsilon<1$ and take an enumeration $E=\{q_n\}_n$ and then pose $\forall n$ $I_n:=(a_n,b_n)\ni q_n$ such that $b_n-a_n<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$.
Now $U:=\cup_n I_n\supseteq E$ open, so $m(U)=\sup\{m(P) \mid P\subseteq U \text{ multi-interval}\}$.

The point is that each time I try to fill $U$ with a multi interval, I am forced to take the single intervals $<\frac{\epsilon}{2^n}$ for some $n$, meaning the series will be $<\epsilon$.

A final notable remark is: it might appear that $\cup I_n \supseteq [0,1]$, but it's NOT the case! This is intuitively because each $q_n$ has indeed a sphere around itself, but the radius of the sphere decreases dramaticallyfast, and there are not enough rationals to keep up with this decay.

Please leave an upvote (on the answer/question) if you found this insight useful!

Comment: I thank all the people who helped me, they all were really useful but this time I only feel satisfied by this reasoning.